# Pandas : plot data frame object with marker?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my `pandas` DataFrame.

```
   value  action
0      1       0
1      2       1
2      3       1
3      4       1
4      3       0
5      2       1
6      5       0
```

What I want to do is mark `value` as `o` if `action=0`, `x` if `action=1`.

So, the plot marker should be like this:
`o x x x o x o`

But have no idea how to do this...

Need your helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
plt.plot(df.index, df.value, '-X', markevery=df.index[df.action==1].tolist())
plt.plot(df.index, df.value, '-o', markevery=df.index[df.action==0].tolist())
```

Result:

[image]

alternative solution:

```
plt.plot(df.index, df.value, '-')
plt.scatter(df.index[df.action==0], df.loc[df.action==0, 'value'],
            marker='o', s=100, c='green')
plt.scatter(df.index[df.action==1], df.loc[df.action==1, 'value'], 
            marker='x', s=100, c='red')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can plot the filtered dataframe. I.e., you can create two dataframes, one for action 0 and one for action 1. Then plot each individually.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"value":[1,2,3,4,3,2,5], "action":[0,1,1,1,0,1,0]})
df0 = df[df["action"] == 0]
df1 = df[df["action"] == 1]

ax = df.reset_index().plot(x = "index", y="value", legend=False, color="gray", zorder=0)
df0.reset_index().plot(x = "index", y="value",kind="scatter", marker="o", ax=ax)
df1.reset_index().plot(x = "index", y="value",kind="scatter",  marker="x", ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want to add `marker` on line plot. How can I do that?

Comment: A line plot can be done via `.plot(kind="line", ...)`.